# Count if another column contains a value

Tags: python, pandas, sumifs

I have a CSV file with two columns:

```
fruits   values
bananas       2
apples        5
oranges       4
pineapples    2
```

I would like to sum the `values` if `fruits` has "apples" in it. It should return 5 + 2 = 7.

I tried this:

```
sum= 0
if folha['fruits'].str.contains("apples"):
    sum=sum+folha['values'].sum()
```

But it returns an error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: are you after: `df.ix[df.fruits.isin(['apples']), 'values'].sum()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward:

```
In [10]: df
Out[10]: 
       fruits  values
0     bananas       2
1      apples       5
2     oranges       4
3  pineapples       2

In [11]: df[df.fruits.str.contains('apples')]['values'].sum()
Out[11]: 7
```

Comment: That worked great! I tried str.contais and isin but I was missing some syntax. Thanx!

Comment: What if I wanted to add another condition from other column? What's the correct syntax on the df[df.fruits.str.contains('apples')]['values'].sum() script?